# Ag-Grid: add a placeholder text in agSelectCellEditor dynamic dropdown options list

Tags: ag-grid

I am using Ag-Grid for displaying tabular data, is there a way we can add a placeholder in the dropdown options which are displayed in a column where we have an agSelectCellEditor?

### Problem Statement:

```
Sample Code:
for(const [key,value] of countryCodes ) {
if (key !== ' ') {
   countryNames.push([value.countriesCd]);
 }
}

console.log(this.countryNames) =  [['France'], ['Belgium'], ['USA'], ['UAE']]


For eg: The column filed  = 'country'

country.cellEditor = 'agSelectCellEditor',
country.singleClickEdit = true,
country.cellEditorParams = {

  values.countryNames,
}
```

---

When clicking on the country column, it shows the select dropdown with the countryNames list and without making any selection it defaults the dropdown to France, its confusing for the users as an option is displayed in the editorCell without selection